# Thread-safety work with static field

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider the code:

```
class InnerClass
{
    public int State { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(InnerClass other) => State == other.State;

    public override int GetHashCode() => State;

    public override string ToString() => State.ToString();
}

class TestClass
{
    private static InnerClass _innerClass;
    private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

    public InnerClass Get()
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            return _innerClass;
        }
    }

    public void Set(InnerClass innerClass)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _innerClass = innerClass;
        }
    }
}

[Fact]
public void TestClassTest()
{
    var firstInnerClass = new InnerClass() {State = 1};
    var secondInnerClass = new InnerClass() {State = 2};

    Assert.NotEqual(firstInnerClass, secondInnerClass);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var testClass = new TestClass();
        testClass.Set(firstInnerClass);

        var currentInnerClass = testClass.Get();
        Task.Run(() => testClass.Set(secondInnerClass));

        Assert.Equal(firstInnerClass, currentInnerClass);
    }
}
```

It does not work. I understand that it is related to `_innerClass` field. Looks like `currentInnerClass` pointer can be replaced later.

But why is the next code work fine then?

```
class TestClass
{
    private static InnerClass _innerClass;

    public InnerClass Get()
    {
        return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _innerClass, _innerClass, _innerClass);
    }

    public void Set(InnerClass innerClass)
    {
        Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _innerClass, innerClass, null);
    }
}
```

So there are two questions:

1. How exactly Interlocked works with memory so that it can work fine?
2. How can I change the first code (with `lock` operator) to make it ok? Maybe MemoryBarrier can help me? I am not sure...

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? How does the output that you get differ from the output you expect? If it throws an error, what does the error say?

Comment: The test fails after some iterations. See the last assertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So lets look at what you are doing here in your loop:

```
// Here you are creating a new TestClass. Should be whole new state, right
//Maybe not...
var testClass = new TestClass();

// Here we set the field to firstInnerClass
testClass.Set(firstInnerClass);

// Here we get the field value. Should be firstInnerClass always, right? Maybe...
var currentInnerClass = testClass.Get();

// Here we create a task to run on another thread.
// This will asynchronously update the state. 
// Might take a while though...
Task.Run(() => testClass.Set(secondInnerClass));

// Here we assert that the state we read is what we set
Assert.Equal(firstInnerClass, currentInnerClass);
```

So far, so good. We write a value, we read a value, we asynchronously kick off a change to that value, and then we confirm that what we read is what we wrote.

The problem lies here:

```
private static InnerClass _innerClass;
```

`static` here means that the field is associated with the type, not the instance. It is shared across all instances of the class. So what is happening is that on some iteration N, the async Task from iteration N-1 is taking long enough to complete that it performs it's update between the write and the read. So the read gets `secondInnerClass`, not `firstInnerClass`. The fact that you are creating a new TestClass is irrelevant- the content fields of that class are static and so shared with every other copy.

If you change TestClass to the following, the error should disappear:

```
class TestClass
{
    private InnerClass _innerClass;
    private readonly object _syncObject = new object();

    public InnerClass Get()
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            return _innerClass;
        }
    }

    public void Set(InnerClass innerClass)
    {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
            _innerClass = innerClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have a static field in the real code. And I don't need workaround. The second sample with interlocked works fine... I just wanted explanations. I asked two questions and do not see any answers here. And I do not understand your point about update between write and read because I try to solve this issue by lock operator.

Comment: Regarding interlocked, I think you are just getting lucky. The use of Iterlocked here and the lock statement are functionally equivalent. You seem to have the wrong idea of what locking does, however. The lock statement prevents multiple threads from accessing the block of code (or other code that is locked on the same value) concurrently. It does not "lock" the value forever though. As soon as the setter exits, another thread can come in and change the value. In your case the task is taking long enough to execute that it is coming in between the write and the read of the next iteration.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I understood it and modified the setter so that it throws an exception when anybody tries to set value again. Thank you for your time and answer,